# BIP deterministic seeds, number of words and compatible wallets

Tags: wallet, seed, bip

I like to have a list of Bitcoin wallets that accepts various types of deterministic seeds. I have read that some seeds can not be imported in e.g. Electrum of other.
So a list with following columns would be ideal for me:
BIP type | word count | compatible wallets

Can someone assist me here please?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I doubt anyone is going to just go look all that information up for you. This site is more geared towards asking questions to help in understanding something. This seems like a bit of research that you will need to do yourself if you really need all that information. Feel free to share your results here, though!

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, the two most common sets of HD wallet mnemonic seeds used are [BIP 39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/bip-0039-wordlists.md) compliant or Electrum Wallet compliant.  Most of the more secure hardware HD wallet devices support the BIP 39 standard, which appears to be deprecating the older set of Electrum HD seed words. People should not have to do a deep dive into Electrum Python code to find the list of wallet mnemonic seeds. The old Armory paper mnemonics backups are too difficult for non-technologists to utilize, and should be treated as deprecated.

With the BIP 44 standard being defined across a plethora of [altcoins](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md), and HD hardware wallet vendors supporting BIP 39, I'm thinking the prevalence or days of using Electrum mnemonic seeds will be numbered.

For whatever reason, Monero cryptocurrency choose to use Electrum seeds, and yet also SLIP 44 registered their altcoin. This confuses wallet developers needing to support Monero while ensuring customer wallet portability across different implementations. End users will demand the simplicity of using one set of mnemonic words to reconstitute their wallets across multiple cryptocurrencies, not two. This means the [reference](https://moneroaddress.org/) offline JavaScript available [at](https://github.com/moneromooo-monero/monero-wallet-generator/) probably needs a redo.

Comment: Located [Electrum English Words](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/mnemonics/english.h)